# Classify Multiple Documents and store them in different folders Via Flask (python)

Tags: python, flask, document, text-classification

I want to do is I want my web app to take multiple documents as input and classify them using my model and store those classified documents into different folders.

I have developed a model which classifies documents. Model is ready and have accuracy of about 0.96 f-score. I want to implement it in flask. I already implemented on text input which shows accurate results.

```
((#LIBRARIES
app = Flask(__name__)

app.config.from_object(__name__) # load config from th

app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] = 'CV_upload/'
app.config['ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS'] = set(['txt', 'pdf', 'png', 'jpg', 
    'jpeg', 'gif'])

# Route for handling the login page logic
@app.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    error = None
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if request.form['username'] != 'admin' or 
    request.form['password'] != 'admin':
            error = 'Invalid Credentials. Please try again.'
        else:
            return redirect(url_for('home'))
    return render_template('index.html', error=error)

@app.route('/logout')
def logout():
    session.pop('logged_in', None)
    flash('You were logged out')
    return redirect(url_for('home'))


@app.route('/home')
def home():
    return render_template('home.html')

@app.route('/predict',methods=['POST'])
def predict():
    <<<<<<<<<<<<<<#MY_NAIVE_BAYES MODEL 
   HERE>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>

<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<THis is where i take input text but i want this to 
   change as input multiple pdf files and then classify them>>>>>>>>
                if request.method == 'POST':
            message = request.form['message']
            data = [message]
            vect = vectorizer.transform(data).toarray()
            my_prediction = model.predict(vect)
            return render_template('result.html',prediction = my_prediction)



if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True , threaded=True) 
))
```

I want to do is I want my web app to take multiple documents as input and classify them using my model and store those classified documents into different folders. When placed a query it will generate the result.

Comment: What exactly will you post request look like ? Will it be just pdf names (with you storing the actual file on the server ), or the complete blob of pdf file ?

Comment: i want 500 to 1000 files load on myserver then it will be used by my model to classify and then store in different classes

Comment: so is you question pertaining to Case 1 or Case 2? Do you already have these files ? Or you want the user to upload it ?
Case 1: How can I create a POST flask route accept / upload multiple files ?
Case 2: How can I run the model I have on pdf files ?

Comment: ok read carefully.....

Comment: 1. i want to upload multiple pdf files on the server...

Comment: then i have developed a module which will convert the pdf file to text .

Comment: after that i want my model which ive developed already which is working fine (with text input/upload text directly and is telling the right class for it).. i want that to also work on multiple files and classify them in different classes.(model is already trained on different classes. all i want to know that when the files are uploaded (which you will tell how to upload and then they are converted to text files) after that how will i link those files to my model that it will classify each file to a class and store it in the folder which will be created with the help of class name.

Comment: check the edited answer

Comment: 1. i want user to upload it.
2. yes i want to run the model on those files

Answer (score 0):

Minimal solution using the [FileUploads](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/patterns/fileuploads/)

```
import os

from flask import Flask, request
from werkzeug.utils import secure_filename

app = Flask(__name__)

def classify(bindata):
    #this is a pdf file, extract text and run your model
    return "abc"

def ensure_dirs(path):
    if not os.path.exists(path):
        os.makedirs(path)

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def upload_file():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        for fileobj in request.files.getlist('file'):
            print "Found {}".format(fileobj.filename)
            binary_data = fileobj.stream.read()
            file_class = classify(binary_data)
            path = "uploads/{}".format(file_class)
            ensure_dirs(path)
            fd = open(os.path.join(path, fileobj.filename), "wb")
            fd.write(binary_data)
            fd.close()
            fileobj.close()
    return '''
    <!doctype html>
    <title>Upload new File</title>
    <h1>Upload new File</h1>
    <form method=post enctype=multipart/form-data>
      <input type=file name=file multiple>
      <input type=submit value=Upload>
    </form>
    '''

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Comment: the question is how to take them as input . ive module for conversion. but the problem is .. how i will make my web app to take them as input and classify each in different classes using the model i designed and then store them in different folders

Comment: So you want to webpage to "upload multiple files" ?